# Facebook SDK for Android - dialog show up and dismissed itself

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I implemented facebook Like button in my app and after clicking it dialog show up with gray facebook logo and the dismisses itself. As far as I know, it should offer to like specified page.

Code:

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
   likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
           "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
           LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

LogCat:

```
 04-14 17:36:07.348  14147-14147/com.klangstudios.fakecall E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
04-14 17:36:07.348  14147-14147/com.klangstudios.fakecall E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
04-14 17:36:07.349  14147-14147/com.klangstudios.fakecall E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
04-14 17:36:07.350  14147-14147/com.klangstudios.fakecall E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
```

Comment: Post the code where your application failed. we can't do much with just the error message.

Comment: @ScarletMerlin well, it doesn't crashes app so LogCat don't specify which line causes it. I know since there are only two lines that I implemented in the code.

Comment: Oh, and I don't have facebook app installed. I read that it may affect that, but Facebook SDK docs say that You login through WebView then: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#fallback

Comment: Are you adding Internet permissions to the app?

Comment: Sure. It was the first thing I checked. I googled it before so basic problems are out.

Comment: Are you using an admin/developer/tester for your app, or a random user?

Comment: @MingLi I'm admin. It's my own app and have full access to everything.

Comment: What's the version of your device or emulator? The Like dialog isn't supported on Gingerbread.

Comment: @GokhanCaglar I'm using Nexus 5 emulator with 4.4.2 and Moto G 1 gen real device (my actual phone) with 5.0.2.

Comment: @MingLi I just added another user as tester, but still the same behavior. I also submited my app so maybe this would help. Quite a bunch of work as for simple Like button I must say.

Comment: Normally it just works, but we can certainly have better error messages in cases where there's failures. Have you tried it on a device with the Facebook app installed?

Comment: @MingLi yes, I have it freshly installed on my Motorola Moto G 1 gen. Everywhere now I get 'cannot connect to the server' error which is better than previous error, but I can't believe that Your servers are down so long ;)

Comment: "Error connecting to Facebook servers. Please try again later." That's the exact error from LogCat (still with PlatformProvider and AttributionIdProvider errors). Tried it on Wi-Fi and normal internet connection.

Comment: The attribution ID errors are benign, and will be fixed in an upcoming SDK release. The error connecting is concerning. Are you able to use the Facebook app as normal?

Comment: Yeah, Facebook app is working perfectly. Should I provide app id for more detailed investigation?

Comment: You should file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs, that way one of our engineers can have a look, and you can also pass confidential information if needed.

Comment: @MingLi two more questions: why Facebook requires privacy policy even for Native Like Button? and is it possible to implement Like button without submitting whole app?

Comment: The Like button does require an app review, and the privacy policy is part of the requirements. You don't need this to test your app though if you're using a developer or tester of the app. 

When you submit your task, please post it here so we can follow up. If you add more details like your app id, and tester id, it will help us debug. You can post those details confidentially on the bug tool.

Comment: @GokhanCaglar I already provided detailes through bug tool and Facebook managed to reproduce this error so I'm waiting now. It's good to see that You guys are around here :)

Comment: @AmerHadi nope, waiting for Facebook to resolve it